# Error in showing data in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting data using this way from i want that i should display date in section title 
 and the    event location in rows which are in appDelegate.book1 array. when this roop runs first then in first section it must show 7 rows in one section and same like that as come but i am not getting required

```
NSArray *activitiesArray;
for (int j=0;j<10; j++) {

    NSDictionary *dictOne = [results objectAtIndex:j];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);
    Date  *aDate = [[Date alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:j]];
    [appDelegate.dates addObject:aDate];
    [aDate release];
    activitiesArray = [dictOne objectForKey:@"events"];


for (int i=0; i<[activitiesArray count]; i++) {

    int testcount =[activitiesArray count];
    NSDictionary *dictTwo = [activitiesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *eventDict=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"event"];
    //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictOne objectForKey:@"date"]);
    //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"]);
    //  NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [eventDict objectForKey:@"location"]);


    NSInteger*date=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];

    NSInteger*affectedDate=[dictTwo objectForKey:@"affectedDate"];


    NSString*appId =[eventDict objectForKey:@"appId"];
    NSString*eventId=[eventDict objectForKey:@"eventId"];
    NSString*location=[eventDict objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString*municipality=[eventDict objectForKey:@"municipality"];
    NSString*title=[eventDict objectForKey:@"title"];




    Book1 *aBook=[[Book1 alloc] initWithDate:date affectedDate:affectedDate location:location municipality:municipality title:title];


    [appDelegate.books1 addObject:aBook];

    int count=[appDelegate.books1 count];
}
}
```

this is the NSLog of count of appDelegate.book1
The value of integer num is 1
       2011-08-09 12:40:31.731 FVN[2409:207] The value of integer num is 2
       2011-08-09 12:40:31.731 FVN[2409:207] The value of integer num is 3
       2011-08-09 12:40:31.731 FVN[2409:207] The value of integer num is 4
       2011-08-09 12:40:31.732 FVN[2409:207] The value of integer num is 5
       2011-08-09 12:40:31.732 FVN[2409:207] The value of integer num is 6
      2011-08-09 12:40:31.733 FVN[2409:207] The value of integer num is 7

so like this array my table view should show 7 items in first section adn like wise above as they are in sequence so how to do this

Comment: Try to improve your question.

Comment: problem is that when i NSlog array appDelegate.book1 its shows 7 values firt time and nine second timing loop so iwant that 7 should appear in first section of data and like wise others

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following two delegate methods in your Table view controller subclass.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; //return the actual number of sections you want
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.

if(section == 0)
   return 7; //actually return your array1's count

if(section == 1)
   return 9; //actually return your array2's count



 }
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: i can do like but when next time loop runs its has 9 so in last array has 86 items so if give 7 or 9 it will not show other values

Comment: The 2nd method is used for returning the number of rows in a particular section. It will not affect other sections.

Comment: so array has 86 items so how it will show 7 line in first section

Comment: i want no of rows in section should be like the no values store in the array in single itteration of loop first time 7 second time 9 for e.g thirs time is 14 etc...

Comment: Lets say your table has 16 items, 7 in the first section & 9 in the second. Edited my answer for this case.

Comment: your saying that i should all the data in different arrays for each section

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on how your data is stored. If it is stored in a data base, you would fetch the result based on some query & return the number of items fetched.

Comment: @ali let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2255/discussion-between-akshay-and-ali)

Comment: this is ok but how i display now in the cell data i have 2 arrays so how display now