# showing data in table view sections from different NSMutableArrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am fetching data form JSON and storing that data in 10 differnet NSMutable Arrays .I want to show that data in 10 sections of the tableview so how to do this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
//return categories.count ;


if(section == 0)
{

    return [appDelegate.books1 count];

}

else if(section == 1)
{
    return [appDelegate.books2 count];

}

else if(section == 2)
{
    return [appDelegate.books3 count];
}

else if(section == 3)
{
    return [appDelegate.books4 count];

}


else if(section == 4)
{
    return [appDelegate.books5 count];
}


else if(section == 5)
{
    return [appDelegate.books6 count];

}



else if(section == 6)
{
    return [appDelegate.books7 count];

}


else if(section == 7)
{
    return [appDelegate.books8 count];
}

else if(section == 8)
{
    return [appDelegate.books9 count];

}
else if(section == 9)
{
    return [appDelegate.books10 count];
}
```

}

if i am doing below it shows only first section

```
       Book1*aBook=[appDelegate.books1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int count=[appDelegate.books1 count];


    cell.text = aBook.municipality;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=aBook.title;


    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: The code you posted looks perfectly fine. What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: its fine how may show that cell value how should i code that section

Comment: Asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992266/error-in-showing-data-in-tableview/6992362#6992362 again.

Comment: @Akshay it was different now i have done all the things only to show them in tableview cell

Comment: I have edited code also given the table view cell code

Comment: why can't you create an array in such a way that NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Book1",[array1],@"Book2",[array2], and so on. it would be easier to handle later

Comment: Are you returning the correct value in - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; //return the actual number of sections you want
}

Comment: yes it shows cell values for one section not for others other are emty

Comment: You are using only books1 in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or is this one case of the switch that you put in it??

Comment: yes that is what i want to know how to use all to set cell values

Answer (score 2):

In my view (if you don't want to change much in your code) do it like this

- make an another `NSMutableArray` object lets say `allData`
- add all your array into `allData` according to section, somthing like this

  ```
  [allDatad addObjects:appDelegate.books1,appDelegate.books2,appDelegate.books3...,appDelegate.books10,nil];
  ```

now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just change this

```
Book1* aBook=[[allData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
int count=[[allData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count];
```

and in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[allData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count];
}
```

Comment: Oops, you posted while i was busy writing my answer which is basically the same thing. Sorry +1 :)

Comment: it gives error in number of rows in section over indexPath.section

Answer (score 0):

Use indexPath.section to determine for which section you are preparing your cell.

For e.g., if indexPath.section is 3 then use appDelegate.books4.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A better more scalable implementation would be to add these arrays to another array, say `arrayOfArrays`. Now your number of sections are

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 
return [arrayOfArrays count];
}
```

number of rows are:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

and your cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//all the dequeueing and initialization and stuff

Book1 *aBook=[[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
int count=[[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count];
cell.text = aBook.municipality;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=aBook.title;

//do other stuff

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
Book1*aBook;


UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}


if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    aBook=[appDelegate.books1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    aBook=[appDelegate.books2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
int count=[appDelegate.books1 count];


cell.text = aBook.municipality;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=aBook.title;


cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: my i set celltext value and return cell inside if or outside

Comment: check my ans and write like it.and continue on indexPath.section ==2 and change your array according to it.

Comment: check my ans and copy pase it. i write code for only 2 section section 0 and section 1 .you have to write it for all section .just check my code it will show data to you for 2 section..

Comment: no i have not change same i have used but it shows only one section

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
Book1*aBook; have you changed this code

Comment: i have copied your code and pasted in my xcode in app but it only show singles all cellForRowAtIndex i have copied

Comment: book1 is data controller class with properties location etc

Comment: write- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return 9;
}

Answer (score 0):

You should store all those arrays in NSMutableDictionary like,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:appDelegate.books1 forKey:@"1"];
    [dict setObject:appDelegate.books2 forKey:@"2"];
    [dict setObject:appDelegate.books3 forKey:@"3"];
```

and access with the reference of indexPath.section while creating cell like,

```
    Book1*aBook = [dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section + 1]];
```

and at time when you want to define numberOfRowsInSection you can get count from the NSMutableDictionary.

```
    Book1*aBook = [dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", section + 1]];
    [aBook count];
```

Comment: while creating dic it gives exception on 2 items  only first works

Comment: Can you please post the exception?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: 1)'

Comment: i have added in comment the exception do reply me

Comment: Need to check your problem with your implemented code. Can you post it?